# Crear tabla con POO en php

Tags: php, poo

Acabo de reformular mi pregunta para empezar de cero. Tengo estos dos archivos de php, tengo que hacer que al ejecutarlo me salga la tabla que muestro abajo, pero antes de eso quiero ir a lo básico y saber como puedo mostrar aunque sea los nombres de los usuarios que estoy mostrando, en plan

Pepe
Lola

y una vez que sepa hacer eso ya investigaré para poder crear la tabla con todos los atributos. No logro mostrar los nombres y es que no sé como hacerlo, ya que los que he realizado solo tenían una clase.He intentado varias cosas en la función graficar pero no logro mostrar nada.

A ver si me podéis echar una mano.

`clase1.php`

```
<?php
class usuario {
  // Definición de los atributos.
  protected $lugar; // lugar del usuario
  protected $nombre; // nombre del usuario
  protected $colores; // array con los colores favoritos del usuario

    public function __construct($unNombre,$unlugar,$unoscolores) {
    // Recibe tres String e instancia un nuevo objeto de la clase con los 
       valores de los parámetros
       $this->nombre=$unNombre; 
       $this->lugar=$unlugar; 
       $this->colores=$unoscolores; 

     }
        public function getNombre() {return ($this->nombre);}
        public function getlugar() {return ($this->lugar);}
        public function getcolores()
        {
         return ($this->colores);
         }
 }
?>
```

`clase0.php`

```
 <?php
 // Definición de una clase base.
 require_once("clase1.php");
 class personas {
     // Definición de los atributos.
     protected $list; //array de objetos de la clase usuario

     public function __construct($losUsuarios) {
         $this->list = $losUsuarios;
     }

     public function graficar() {
     /*He intentado lo siguiente para que me muestre al menos los nombres
         echo $this->lista->getNombre();
         echo $datos->getNombre();


     */

 }
 }
 /* Si ejecuto
 $datos[] = new usuario('Pepe','Madrid.','verde*rojo*blanco*azul');
 $datos[] = new usuario('Lola','Valencia.','rosa*morado*naranja*azul celeste');
 $lasPersonas=new personas($datos);
 $lasPersonas->graficar(); //
 ?>
```

Me debe mostrar una tabla así:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No veo que si quieras hayas intentando hacer el `graficar`. Por favor, podrías [edit] tu pregunta y agregar el código que intentaste?

Comment: tambien, por favor, tabula correctamente tu codigo, pues sino pones dificultad a su entendimiento.

Comment: Acabo de editar, es que fui intentando probar varias cosas pero al no salir fui borrando por eso no pues nada. Eso es de un ejemplo que vi para crear una tabla pero no sé como aplicarlo a mi ejercicio o si tiene que ver.

Comment: estas cosas asi. `$this - > finTabla();`con el guion y el mayorque separados, es incorrecto. En su lugar debes utilizarlo junto, como  `$this->finTabla();`

Comment: Gracias, en mi código lo tengo junto pero al darle formato para ponerlo aquí se han separado.

Comment: Después de semana y media sigo sin saber como mostrar aunque sea los nombres. ¿Alguna ayuda?